# Dropwdown List with selected Value in Jsp

Tags: jsp

I have a static HTML list in JSP something like below

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="OPTION1">OPTION1</option>
    <option value="OPTION2">OPTION2</option>
    <option value="OPTION3">OPTION3</option>
</select>
```

I would like to set the selected value for the drop down list equal to ${model.option} , how can i do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in the value of your first option and give it a s`elected` attribute:

```
<select>
   <option value="${model.option}" selected></option>
   <option value="OPTION1">OPTION1</option>
   <option value="OPTION2">OPTION2</option>
   <option value="OPTION3">OPTION3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't want the first one to be selected all the time , model.option can return anything option1, option2 or option3 and based on the value I want the item in the drop down list selected

Comment: It's not the first one, it's the value that you get from model.option .